# How do I return a specified size for an arraylist?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to return a specific number of elements in my list. I am aware that the `size()` method returns the total number of elements in a list. But I would only like to return 3 elements from my list. How would I go about doing this?

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stockInformaiton.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by this code: (It will show only 3 items if the list contains at least 3 items, otherwise, it will show 0 or 1 or 2 items.)

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int sz = stockInformaiton.size();
    if (sz < 3) {
        return sz;
    }
    return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.List#subList

```
/**
 * Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
 * {@code fromIndex}, inclusive, and {@code toIndex}, exclusive.  (If
 * {@code fromIndex} and {@code toIndex} are equal, the returned list is
 * empty.)  The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural
 * changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.
 * The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported
 * by this list.<p>
 *
 * This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of
 * the sort that commonly exist for arrays).  Any operation that expects
 * a list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view
 * instead of a whole list.  For example, the following idiom
 * removes a range of elements from a list:
 * <pre>{@code
 *      list.subList(from, to).clear();
 * }</pre>
 * Similar idioms may be constructed for {@code indexOf} and
 * {@code lastIndexOf}, and all of the algorithms in the
 * {@code Collections} class can be applied to a subList.<p>
 *
 * The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if
 * the backing list (i.e., this list) is <i>structurally modified</i> in
 * any way other than via the returned list.  (Structural modifications are
 * those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such
 * a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)
 *
 * @param fromIndex low endpoint (inclusive) of the subList
 * @param toIndex high endpoint (exclusive) of the subList
 * @return a view of the specified range within this list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException for an illegal endpoint index value
 *         ({@code fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size ||
 *         fromIndex > toIndex})
 */
List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);
```